# Using defined value in include

Tags: c++, c, compilation, c-preprocessor

I have `#include` file structures like following:

```
#include <core/mod1/file1.hpp>
#include <core/mod1/file2.hpp>
#include <core/mod1/mod2/.../modN/fileN.hpp>
```

And there are such includes in each file. For example, in file `core/mod1/file1.hpp` there might be `#include <core/mod3/file5.hpp>`.
Here `core` is the name of my library. But I want to use `core_new` instead of `core` in the entire project, without modifying all files (actually a lot).
I have tried to add a `#define core core_new`, hoping that is will kind of substitute what I need:

```
#define core core_new
#include <core/mod1/file1.hpp>
#include <core/mod1/file2.hpp>
#include <core/mod1/mod2/.../modN/fileN.hpp>
```

But it does NOT do it: `core/mod1/file1.hpp` is being included instead of `core_new/mod1/file1.hpp`.
Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Have you considered setting the include path instead? `c++ -Icore` vs `c++ -Icode_new` and use all as `#include <mod1/file1.hpp>`?

Comment: Consider a massive replace (it's probably a well defined and easily specified pattern to replace)... or consider defining a symbolic link between core and core_new...

Comment: Basically what I want is to avoid modifying ALL sources...

Comment: Note: It is possible to build up a string that contains the filename to `#include` -- however this would still require you to change all your `#include` lines to use the built-up string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the file system, not the C++ compiler.  Make a new directory and copy/link all your source files over to there.  Change the `-I` option in your compiler to to use this new directory.  Of course, have your new files in the the new `core` directory.  This way you don't need to edit a single source/header file.

Comment: Yes, this would work. Another problem is that I cannot change any compile options.

Comment: You can't change compile neither sources? How is this possible

Comment: I know that this sounds unbelievable :)
But this is a really big project, and I am not the only owner.

Answer (score 1):

You can try make a symlink from core_new to core. For example in *nix machines using `ln` command.

```
ln -s /path/to/core_new /path/to/core
```

This does not create a copy rather it creates a link to core_new with name core

you can also move contents of core to another folder before symlink

```
mv /path/to/core /path/to/core_old
```